# C# OpenFileDialog repeating the execution on multiselect

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm using the OpenFileDialog component on C# to select multiple files to process.

The problem is that when the program finishes the execution of the foreach loop, it is repeating the "private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)" method, messing up my excel spreadsheet.

How to deal with that?

Here is my code:

```
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

    int i = 2;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    xla.Visible = true;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Test case";
    ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Q Score";
    ws.Cells[1, 3] = "TC Score";

    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader arq = new StreamReader(file);

            string Title = file;
            Title = Title.Remove(0, Title.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            Title = Title.Remove(Title.LastIndexOf("."), Title.Length - Title.LastIndexOf("."));
            string Title_aux = Title;
            F.Text = "MSA-GA: " + Title;

            string texto = arq.ReadToEnd();

            arq.Close();
            arq.Dispose();
            openFileDialog1.Dispose();

            texto = texto.Replace(" ","");
            texto = texto.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
            texto = texto.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "");

            StreamWriter gravar = new StreamWriter(@"cases\" + Title + ".FASTA");
            gravar.Write(texto);
            gravar.Close();
            gravar.Dispose();

            string Title_ref = Title.Substring(0, (Title.Length - 2));

            // Start the child process.
            Process p = new Process();
            // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c program -test cases\\" + Title + ".FASTA " + "-ref cases\\" + Title_ref;
            //p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dir";
            p.Start();
            // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
            // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
            // p.WaitForExit();
            // Read the output stream first and then wait.
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            int pos_ini = output.IndexOf("Q=")+2;
            string q_score = output.Substring(pos_ini, (output.IndexOf(';', pos_ini) - pos_ini));

            pos_ini = output.IndexOf("TC=") + 3;
            string tc_score = output.Substring(pos_ini, (output.IndexOf("\r\n", pos_ini) - pos_ini));

            q_score=q_score.Replace('.', ',');
            tc_score=tc_score.Replace('.', ',');

            ws.Cells[i, 1] = Title;
            ws.Cells[i, 2] = q_score;
            ws.Cells[i, 3] = tc_score;

            i++;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the method:

```
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
```

is being called, through `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Fasta File";
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Never use an empty try-catch.

Comment: Yeah, I know. This is just a quick test. But it's not the problem :( Thanks

Comment: If `openFileDialog1_FileOk()` is being called more than once then you should provide code showing how it is being called. I don't see the issue in the method itself.

Comment: It's being called on openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() execution. I've edited the post.

Comment: Don't use the FileOk event.  It is meant to reject selected file(s), not to use the dialog result.  Don't start the foreach loop until ShowDialog() returned with DialogResult.OK

Answer (score -1):

There are sure some problems in your code, but not what you mentioned. The ShowDialog() opens the dialog and fires all wired events. So check your event assignments if the openFileDialog1_FileOk is being called more than once. Right click on the openFileDialog1_FileOk method in Visual Studio and select "Find All References", check if there is any unusual reference or something.